# Android inter process communication BroadcastReceiver, AIDL

Tags: android, performance, ipc

I'm developing an application where it should be possible to receive some Objects from other applications (Server).
As a developer of a Client application it should be as easy as possible to implement the stuff which is needed to send Objects to my Server application.

I have already read alot about BroadcastReceivers, AIDL, Messenger.

On most sites, it is suggested to use AIDL or Messenger (which uses AIDL internally). But why not use a BroadcastReceiver? It is very easy to use and works just fine. Is it draining battery or lacking performance?

Which "technology" should I use for my application? BroadcastReceiver? AIDL? Messenger? ContentProvider? Unix pipes?

Are there any good websites / books which explain this kind of communication?

Comment: basically with AIDL you can have better interfece for your need (as build tools would generet java code and you should not care about underlaying implementation) ... when BroadcastReceiver has only one interface ...

Comment: I'm only sending one Object which contains other Objects of information. So a BroadcastReceiver would be working fine? Sometimes I need to transfer alot of objects, is a BroadcastReceiver lacking performance?

Comment: 1. IMHO BroadcastReceiver is build on RPC with IIntentSender.aidl/IIntentReceiver.aidl 2. There should be almost no differences in performance between AIDL solution and BroadcasrReceiver (imho receiver would have few calls more but witout significant preformance cost) ... 3. *Sometimes I need to transfer alot of objects* then you should remeber about Intent's size limitation ... maybe ContentProvider for "alot of objects"  would be better

Answer (score 0):

BroadcastReceivers are relatively an older concept, which some times makes security at stake without right permissions, usually you may get requirements to enhance your service to make multiple calls, so AIDL would be an easier option